# Neo4j - get distinct count of clusters that a value is in that cluster

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the distinct count of clusters that contains a certain value from a list of values.

Dataset:

```
CREATE 
(a1: node {tag: "a"}),
(a2: node {tag: "a"}),
(a3: node {tag: "a"}),
(a4: node {tag: "a"}),
(b1: node {tag: "b"}),
(b2: node {tag: "b"}),
(c1: node {tag: "c"}),
(a1)-[:LINKS_TO]->(a2),
(a4)-[:LINKS_TO]->(b1),
(a4)-[:LINKS_TO]->(c1)
```

[image]

I would like to get a distinct count of clusters for each distinct value of `tag`.

- a: 3.

  - There are 4 nodes that has `tag: a`, but they are in 3 distinct clusters, cluster 1,2,3
- b: 2.

  - b appears in 2 distinct clusters, cluster 3, 4
- c: 1.

  - c appears in 1 distinct clusters, cluster 3

I attempted to get a distinct list of tag value and list of clusters through below query, but I am not sure how I should proceed to join/link the 2 lists to get the expected distinct count.

```
MATCH (node)
WITH collect(distinct node.tag) AS tag_list, collect(node) AS clusters
RETURN tag_list, clusters
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that doesn't depend on a cluster attribute:

```sql
MATCH (n:node) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS { (n)--+(m:node) WHERE n.tag = m.tag AND id(n) > id(m) }
RETURN n.tag AS tag, count(*) AS numClusters
```

Result:

| tag | numClusters |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | 3 |
| "b" | 2 |
| "c" | 1 |

This works because if a cluster has at least one node with a given tag, it will only return the one with the lowest id.

Comment: This works! The only minor modification I need to make is changing `--+` to `-[]-` since I am using an older version of Neo4j. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If, as your question originally stated, each `node` node contains a `cluster` property, this simple query:

```
MATCH (n:node)
RETURN n.tag AS tag, COLLECT(DISTINCT n.cluster) AS clusters
```

gets the result:

```
╒═══╤═════════╕
│tag│clusters │
╞═══╪═════════╡
│"a"│[1, 2, 3]│
├───┼─────────┤
│"b"│[3, 4]   │
├───┼─────────┤
│"c"│[3]      │
└───┴─────────┘
```

On the other the other hand, if there is no `cluster` property, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78077489/974731) to see how to use the neo4j Graph Data Science Library's WCC algorithm to efficiently calculate the `componentId` for each node (where a "component" is the same as what you call a "cluster"). (But @FinbarGood's answer should work fine if you do not have much data and all clusters are small.)

Once you have created the GDS projection, like this:

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
  'myGraph',
  'node',
  'LINKS_TO'
)
```

you can get your desired results this way:

```
CALL gds.wcc.stream('myGraph') YIELD nodeId, componentId
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).tag AS tag, COLLECT(DISTINCT componentId) AS clusters
```

Afterwards, you should [drop the GDS projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-drop/) to free up server memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first! Sorry for my mistake of introducing the attribute `cluster` when creating the sample data(to make the sample data more understandable). There is no such attribute in my actual use case to indicate which cluster a node is in. Do we have some way to work without the attribute, please?